# Chart Area Axis Length Mismatch

Tags: .net, vb.net, charts, data-visualization, finance

I have created a chart control (formally Dundas Chart, but this is the standard chart control since 4.0) in a Winforms application that has two areas. The top area is a "stock" graph and the lower area is a "column" graph. The two areas of this chart control are lined up equally on the right but vary on the left.

The following picture has red arrows displaying the difference in length  between the two areas.

[image]

For these two areas to work together, they must be of equal lengths along the x-axis so that each marker on the top area is lined up with the marker on the bottom. While the difference between them is minimal for small datasets, it is much more noticeable as that changes.

I think the reason for the difference between the two is that they are different chart types. I have tried getting the length of the upper area in hopes of scaling, but there does not appear to be a way to get the axis length.

I would greatly appreciate any links, advice or even speculation in regards to solving this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of research I was able to isolate the problem. Within the chartarea of each graph exists an innerplotposition structure which contains values pertaining to the X and Y axis as well as height, width and auto scaling. I set each chartarea to not automatically scale and matched the values of each chartarea from within innerplotposition. This aligned the graphs properly.

On a side note, since it is valuable and related, the chart area also has a position structure which allows for chart area positioning (such as raising the charts in relation to each other).